# Store hex value into NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, hex

I'm confused on how to store a hex value into NSData. I want the value I will be storing to be `0x0F`.

Please could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how I've done that before:

```
UInt8 j= 0x0f;
NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&j length:sizeof(j)] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 20):

You can create an array to hold your hex values and then use that to create the data:

```
unsigned char bytes[] = {0x0F};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:1];
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(unsigned char[]){0x0F} length:1];
```